# install sub package in a parent folder with setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am tryiny to set up my package so it can be `pip` installed from github. 
I have a folder structure with the following format

```
\TopPackage
    |- __init__.py
    |- setup.py
    |- \packageA
        |- __init__.py
        |-moduleA.py
     |- \packageB
        |- __init__.py
        |-moduleB.py
```

my `setup.py` looks file

```py
import setuptools
from setuptools import  find_packages

setuptools.setup(
    name="TopPackage",
    version="1.0",
    packages=find_packages()

)
```

This works and everything installed but to only thing that installed is the sub packags. 
So I have to do the following to use the package:

```py
import packageA

packageA.module()
```

I want from to be in the parent directory. so that to import then I have to write;

```py
from TopPackage import packageA

packageA.module()
```

How can I set up this file structure in the package install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure you directories and files:

```
/AnyName
    |- setup.py
    |- /TopPackage
        |- __init__.py
        |- /packageA
            |- __init__.py
            |-moduleA.py
         |- /packageB
            |- __init__.py
            |-moduleB.py
```